# Vertically connected images with line - CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

can anyone please suggest a method for creating a div portion like in the image. The height should depend on the outer div. I need to use this as a separator between two divs with text on its left and right. Each circled image should come next to the related heading

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want? a div with a bunch of images aligned vertically?

Comment: @Simon : Not only aligned. I know how to align images vertically. But here I need to connect them using a vertical line with two circles on top and bottom. I hope now you get an idea on what i need.

Comment: Why would you implement this with css? I think it would be much easier with some images. Or maybe consider canvas?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html

Comment: @Simon : I tried with Images But as you can see in my question there are two divs on its left and right with some text. So each circled image should come next to the related heading. I have attached one more image with the divs. I don't know what is the exact word to call this type requirement.. something like "Timeline"

Comment: I would go with @AasimHussainKhan's suggestion, just have some sub sections with their own images

Comment: try my code below, may be this will help you out

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan : Thanks Aasim.. Let me try your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, may be this will help u, it is fully responsive too

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    <title>Timeline (responsive) - Bootsnipp.com</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

    .timeline:before {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 3px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -1.5px;
    }

    .timeline > li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 26px;
                right: -15px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 15px solid transparent;
                border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
                border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
                border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 27px;
                right: -14px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 14px solid transparent;
                border-left: 14px solid #fff;
                border-right: 0 solid #fff;
                border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
            color: #fff;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -25px;
            background-color: #999999;
            z-index: 100;
            border-top-right-radius: 50%;
            border-top-left-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        }

        .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
            float: right;
        }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 15px;
                left: -15px;
                right: auto;
            }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 14px;
                left: -14px;
                right: auto;
            }

.timeline-badge.primary {
    background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
    background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

    .timeline-body > p + p {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }
}
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert = function(){};
        var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
        function changeCSS(css){
            if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
            else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
          window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'http://bootsnipp.com');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 id="timeline">Timeline</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
              <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 11 hours ago via Twitter</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
              <p>Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi. Aenean vel dui dui. Nullam leo erat, aliquet quis tempus a, posuere ut mi. Ut scelerisque neque et turpis posuere pulvinar pellentesque nibh ullamcorper. Pharetra in mattis molestie, volutpat elementum justo. Aenean ut ante turpis. Pellentesque laoreet mé vel lectus scelerisque interdum cursus velit auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac mauris lectus, non scelerisque augue. Aenean justo massa.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
              <hr>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4 class="timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.. Let me try this one and will let you know with the results

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="circle_small">0</div>
<div class="circle">Step 1</div>
<div class="circle">Step 2</div>
<div class="circle">Step 3</div>
<div class="circle_small_last">0</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.circle_small{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    left:15px;
  }
.circle_small_last{
  position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    left:15px;
}
.circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
.circle:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.circle:before {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -54px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.circle:first-child:before {
    display: none;
}

.circle_small_last:before {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -54px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.circle_small_last:last-child:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical time line by Codyhouse! first you have to need call `reset css, style css and jQuery` I used `png` image but `SVG` would be better!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var timelineBlocks = $('.cd-timeline-block'),
    offset = 0.8;

  //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
  hideBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);

  //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
    setTimeout(function() {
      showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);
    }, 100): window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);
    });
  });

  function hideBlocks(blocks, offset) {
    blocks.each(function() {
      ($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * offset) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
    });
  }

  function showBlocks(blocks, offset) {
    blocks.each(function() {
      ($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * offset && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden')) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
main {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  color: #7f8c97;
  background-color: #e9f0f5;
}

a {
  color: #acb7c0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.cd-container {
  /* this class is used to give a max-width to the element it is applied to, and center it horizontally when it reaches that max-width */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cd-container::after {
  /* clearfix */
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #303e49;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  header {
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

#cd-timeline {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em 0;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#cd-timeline::before {
  /* this is the vertical line */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background: #d7e4ed;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #cd-timeline {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
  #cd-timeline::before {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
  }
}

.cd-timeline-block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.cd-timeline-block:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cd-timeline-block:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.cd-timeline-block:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-block {
    margin: 4em 0;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.cd-timeline-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px white, inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 3px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.cd-timeline-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.cd-timeline-img.cd-picture {
  background: #75ce66;
}

.cd-timeline-img.cd-movie {
  background: #c03b44;
}

.cd-timeline-img.cd-location {
  background: #f0ca45;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-img.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-img.bounce-in {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.cd-timeline-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #d7e4ed;
}

.cd-timeline-content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cd-timeline-content h2 {
  color: #303e49;
}

.cd-timeline-content p,
.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more,
.cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
}

.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more,
.cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cd-timeline-content p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
  float: right;
  padding: .8em 1em;
  background: #acb7c0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

.no-touch .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more:hover {
  background-color: #bac4cb;
}

.cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 0;
  opacity: .7;
}

.cd-timeline-content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-timeline-content h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more,
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 1.6em;
    width: 45%;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content::before {
    top: 24px;
    left: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: white;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
    float: left;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 122%;
    top: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content {
    float: right;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content::before {
    top: 24px;
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: white;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
    float: right;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    left: auto;
    right: 122%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-content.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-content.bounce-in {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  /* inverse bounce effect on even content blocks */
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content.bounce-in {
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
      <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Movie">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde?</p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
      <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Title of section 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, obcaecati, quisquam id molestias eaque asperiores voluptatibus cupiditate error assumenda delectus odit similique earum voluptatem doloremque dolorem ipsam quae rerum quis. Odit,
        itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos repellat consequuntur perferendis enim amet quae quasi repudiandae sed quod veniam dolore possimus rem voluptatum eveniet eligendi quis fugiat
        aliquam sunt similique aut adipisci.</p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
      <span class="cd-date">Jan 24</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Location">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Title of section 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
      <span class="cd-date">Feb 14</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Location">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Title of section 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum.</p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
      <span class="cd-date">Feb 18</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4yP2cI.png" alt="Movie">
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h2>Final Section</h2>
      <p>This is the content of the last section</p>
      <span class="cd-date">Feb 26</span>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
</section>
<!-- cd-timeline -->
```